# SQL Server 2008 Database Project OR SQL Server Data-tier Application?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

What the difference betwee a "SQL Server 2008 Database Project" and a "SQL Server Data-tier Application"? When would I use each?

Answer (score 2):

A database project is a more fully featured project.  Use it when you require the full set of objects in a normal SQL Server 2008 database.

A data-tier application project only supports a subset of a database project.  Use it when you don't require most of the objects, or want to create just a simple project using the commonly use objects.
Edit: Features of a data-tier application project and commonly used objects are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362013%28VS.100%29.aspx